# Pandas groupby and add additional column and retain other columns in same DF

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a df with 2 rows containing title,url,sku,price,mrp columns and i need to group by and add additional column which is sum of price and sum of mrp

EX DF

| Base SKU | Price | MRP | Title | url | Prod Sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 110 | abcd | [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) | 1_a |
| 1 | 50 | 55 | abcd | [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) | 1_b |

expected output

| Base SKU | Price | MRP | Title | url | Prod Sku | Combined Price | Combined MRP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 110 | abcd | [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) | 1_a | 150 | 165 |
| 1 | 50 | 55 | efgh | [www.efgh.com](http://www.efgh.com) | 1_b | 150 | 165 |

i have tried
1.

```
updated_df = df.groupby(['Base SKU']).agg({'Price': 'sum','MRP':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

but output iam getting is

| Base SKU | Combined Price | Combined MRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 165 |
| 1 | 150 | 165 |

2.

```
updated_df = df.groupby(['Base SKU']).agg({'Price': 'sum','MRP':'sum','Title': 'first', 'url': 'first','Prod Sku': 'first'}).reset_index()
```

but output getting is

| Base SKU | Price | MRP | Title | url | Prod Sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | 165 | abcd | [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) | 1_a |

is there any way to get expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html)

```
df['Combined MRP'] = df.groupby(['Base SKU'])['MRP'] \
                       .transform('sum')
```

The catch is that `transform` will broadcast the results back to the original size of each group, making assignment way easier.